# Hibernate @OneToOne with formula - A column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, formula, outer-join

I have an entity, let's call it `Policy`. `Policy` is hold by `PolicyHolder`s. Not all of them at once, just one, but they can change over time. I can easily map `PolicyHolder`s to policy using `@OneToMany` annotation. But one of the holders is special, because it's current one. I need special, most likely transient, field which can keep its reference.

One of the problems is there is no strict discriminator to distinguish current holder from others. The only way to find out which one of them is this special, I need to find the latest annex when holder was added. In theory it can be easily done by the query and subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM holders h 
WHERE h.policy_id = :myPolicyId AND h.annex_id = 
(SELECT MAX(annex_id) FROM holders sh WHERE sh.policy_id = h.policy_id)
```

It looks like good idea to map current `PolicyHolder` as a field is to use `@JoinColumnOrFormulas` annotation. I tried it like this:

```
public class Policy {

    @OneToMany(...)
    private Set<PolicyHolder> holders;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnOrFormulas({
      @JoinColumnOrFormula(
        column = @JoinColumn(columnName = "policy_id", referencedColumnName = "policy_id")),
      @JoinColumnOrFormula(
        formula = "SELECT MAX(annex_id) FROM holders h WHERE h.policy_id = policyId", 
        referencedColumnName = "annex_id")      
      )
    })
    private PolicyHolder currentHolder;
}
```

I don't even know if this piece of above code works. I can't check it right now and it was written in notepad. Anyway it works for me in the way Hibernate generated correct query. But query didn't executed on Oracle database with error message: `A column may not be outer-joined to a subquery` (why?).

Ok, so I tried to force Hibernate to generate inner join instead of outer. It's safe as there is always at least one `policy holder` for a `policy`. I tried to set the column as `nullable = false` (I know - it's for schema generation) and `optional = false`. But without any result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and I also couldn't make hibernate generate an inner join. Outer join cannot be done with a subquery unfortunatelly (as you have already noticed). So my solution although not the best one was to create a function in oracle. Then it will become:

```
 @ManyToOne
@JoinColumnOrFormulas({
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(
    column = @JoinColumn(columnName = "policy_id", referencedColumnName = "policy_id")),
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(
    formula = "getMaxAnnexForPolicy(policyId)", 
    referencedColumnName = "annex_id")      
  )
})
private PolicyHolder currentHolder;
```

And create a function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function getMaxAnnexForPolicy
   ( policyId in varchar2)
   RETURN varchar2
IS
   res varchar2(200);
BEGIN
 SELECT MAX(annex_id) into res FROM holders h WHERE h.policy_id = policyId;
RETURN res;
end getMaxAnnexForPolicy;
```

I know it is a workaround but it works fine in my scenario. If it is a function hibernate knows it will return just one row. Otherwise it doesn't evaluate the query to see you have added max() and it will also return one row